# Apache Spark - one Spark core divided into several CPU cores

Tags: apache-spark, worker, cpu-cores

I have a question about Apache Spark. I set up an Apache Spark standalone cluster on my Ubuntu desktop. Then I wrote two lines in the `spark_env.sh` file: `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4` and `SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1`. (I found that `export` is not necessary in `spark_env.sh` file if I start the cluster after I edit the `spark_env.sh` file.)

I wanted to have 4 worker instances in my single desktop and let them occupy 1 CPU core each. And the result was like this:

```
top - 14:37:54 up  2:35,  3 users,  load average: 1.30, 3.60, 4.84
Tasks: 255 total,   1 running, 254 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  :  1.7 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 98.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 41.6 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.4 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu4  :  0.3 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu5  :  0.3 us,  0.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 99.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu6  : 59.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 41.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu7  :100.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,  0.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:  16369608 total, 11026436 used,  5343172 free,    62356 buffers
KiB Swap: 16713724 total,      360 used, 16713364 free.  2228576 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND               
10829 aaaaaa    20   0 42.624g 1.010g 142408 S 101.2  6.5   0:22.78 java                  
10861 aaaaaa    20   0 42.563g 1.044g 142340 S 101.2  6.7   0:22.75 java                  
10831 aaaaaa    20   0 42.704g 1.262g 142344 S 100.8  8.1   0:24.86 java                  
10857 aaaaaa    20   0 42.833g 1.315g 142456 S 100.5  8.4   0:26.48 java                  
 1978 aaaaaa    20   0 1462096 186480 102652 S   1.0  1.1   0:34.82 compiz                
10720 aaaaaa    20   0 7159748 1.579g  32008 S   1.0 10.1   0:16.62 java                  
 1246 root      20   0  326624 101148  65244 S   0.7  0.6   0:50.37 Xorg                  
 1720 aaaaaa    20   0  497916  28968  20624 S   0.3  0.2   0:02.83 unity-panel-ser       
 2238 aaaaaa    20   0  654868  30920  23052 S   0.3  0.2   0:06.31 gnome-terminal
```

I think `java` in the first 4 lines are Spark workers. If it's correct, it's nice that there are four Spark workers and each of them are using 1 physical core each (e.g., `101.2%`).

But I see that 5 physical cores are used. Among them, `CPU0, CPU3, CPU7` are fully used. I think one Spark worker is using one of those physical cores. It's fine.

However, the usage levels of `CPU2` and `CPU6` are `41.6%` and `59.0%`, respectively. They add up to `100.6%`, and I think one worker's job is distributed to those 2 physical cores.

With `SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=4` AND `SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1`, is this a normal situation? Or is this a sign of some errors or problems?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly normal behavior. Whenever Spark uses term core it actually means either process or thread and neither one is bound to a single core or processor.

In any multitasking environment processes are not executed continuously. Instead, operating system is constantly switching between different processes which each one getting only small share of available processor time.